# Android: Is android emulator already rooted

Tags: android, shell, resize, command, adb

I am trying to call shell command on a emulator programmatically from my program. I looked at the adb terminal and it was written

> root@generic_x86

I can call wm size 600x800 in terminal to resize but my program can't resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adb shell` session runs with `shell` (or `root` in case of emulator or rooted device) `UID`. Your app (and all subprocesses it spawns) still run with its own `UID`. You still need to manually elevate your privileges (by using `su`) even when running on an emulator or a rooted device.

Comment: how can i do this .. I really need to test on a emulator with su privileges

Comment: @Simon Your question has just been answered. No need to [duplicate it](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/163480/android-how-to-root-an-android-emulator) - the correct answer to it will be similar. _"how can i do this"_ - this is a new question. Close this question and ask another one.